# Can I have two MAC addresses which only differ by the "local" bit?

Tags: linux, networking, mac-address

I have two NICs on my PC. One is the built-in wired Ethernet controller, another one is the plugged-in USB-Ethernet gadget. For the latter, the MAC address is auto-generated by the Linux driver. I'd like to enforce the 'uniqueness' of the usb0 MAC address.

The question is: Can I assign the eth0 MAC to usb0 and set the "local" bit in the address, i.e.:
eth0: 00:0d:88:73:d8:21
usb0: 02:0d:88:73:d8:21

How safe it is in local network?

Thanks in advance.
I'm aware of that the system-generated MAC for usb0 would be safe enough as it is to not match any of the existing MACs in the network. Nevertheless, if you have something to answer to the question above, I'd appreciate that.

Comment: What does a MAC address have to do with "safety" exactly?

Comment: It is safe but pointless. Your auto-generated USB NIC mac address will never match your built-int NIC mac address and this is all you want to know.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean safe as in there is no duplicate mac address, I wouldn't worry unless you some how manage to find the same nic with the same mac somewhere in your local network its doubtful you will cause a problem.

I use the same range on my VM's that change one bit in the hosts NIC mac and havn't hit a problem yet